# Cardview - fix view - attach to bottom

Tags: android, android-cardview

my problem now:

I need to "attach" these two buttons to bottom - I do not want them to be available to be scrolled (only on bottom - always visible). But my Edittext needs to be **scrollable**, because there is long text. In android studio it looks good, but in APP not.

XML

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#212121"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/storyTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/choiceButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="You continue your course to Earth. Two days later, you receive a transmission from HQ saying that they have detected some sort of anomaly on the surface of Mars near an abandoned rover. They ask you to investigate, but ultimately the decision is yours because your mission has already run much longer than planned and supplies are low."
        android:textColor="#9E9E9E"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#212121"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choiceButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="CONTINUE HOME TO EARTH"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#212121"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choiceButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="STOP AND INVESTIGATE"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Everything is in:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_story"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.project.StoryActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

[IN STUDIO - CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UfAW.jpg)

[IN APP - CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR78C.png) - scrollable, but it "doesnt fit"

I hope you understand my problem, thank you guys :)

Comment: What's wrong with you?

Comment: What is wrong with your view?

Comment: What is wrong with your View :P

Comment: I want to implement cardview, for better looking UI, but I have no idea, how to implement it to this XML right :/ @SavinSharma

Comment: You can give padding to your card view.. It will give a little shadow to your cardview which looks better. Add this to line in your cardview 
card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: Can you show your cardview?

Comment: Oh, you didnt undestand :/ I mean, when I try to remake this XML with Cardview, I will always screwup it, so I do not have Cardview @SavinSharma

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html and https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

go through this and add the views that you want to go with cardview inside that, then if you have a problem post it.. do not post even before you try! grrr

Comment: @CharukaSilva Sorry man, I was trying it before, as I said, I always screwed it, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

to the bottom buttons,

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

second button

```
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_button"
```

to make the EditText scrollable,

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: Amazing !!! I had to do few cahnges, but this helped me a lot ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use the cardView for the layout shown in the image(Use a Relative Layout).
To use the cardView,
[(screen shot is shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8zIo.png)
You should add 
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
         to build.gradle(Module :app) file
cardElevation will make a margin to get the shadow.

in xml,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#212121"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <!--your layout contents ...-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#212121">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/StoryImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/storyTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/choiceButton1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/StoryImageView"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              TEXT TEXT TEXT
              "
            android:textColor="#9E9E9E"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choiceButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/choiceButton2"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#212121"
            android:text="button1"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choiceButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#212121"
            android:text="button2"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isnt what I meant :) can you check my updated post?